# Compare multi rows with a row in SQL Server 2008

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

I have an asp.net C# project, for study case, "A University Website"

I have a table called `Agenda` and it contain 9 columns

```
[AgendaId]   uniqueidentifier
[MatirelId]
[InstructorId]
[ClassId]
[AddedDate]
[Semester]
[StartTime]
[EndTime]
[DaySchedule]
```

and it shows what the material is available, which instructor, in which days, in which time will start and will end, in which class, in the same semester.

What I need: when I add a new row, I should check if it is a overlapping of an existing row. 
If it is have an overlapping , give me an error.

PS: instructorId, MatirelId and ClassId are foreign keys into other tables.

Prefer to make it in a stored procedure in SQL Server 2008.

Kindly & Best Regards

Comment: What part are you having trouble with?

Comment: when i add new record, check if it duplicate with previous records 
on the table 
other way , check all fields { except 2 filed "AgnedaId , AddedDate" no need to check it } if it duplicate  with the new record

Comment: Are you looking for exact duplicate, or overlapping Start/End times for same Matirel/Instructor/Class/Semester ?

Comment: Nikola Markovinovic: yah it's overlapping .:P

Comment: When you want to notify somebody put `@` in front of his/hers name. So, is your issue resolved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that **all** columns have to match for a duplicate - then you'd use something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.InsertNewRow 
    @AgendaId      uniqueidentifier.,
    @MatirelId     int,   -- you did not mention what *types* those columns have - adapt as needed!
    @InstructorId  int,
    @ClassId       int,
    @AddedDate     datetime,
    @Semester      int
    @StartTime     time(7),
    @EndTime       time(7),
    @DaySchedule   int
AS BEGIN
   IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.Agenda 
              WHERE MatirelId = @MatirelId
                AND InstructorId = @InstructorId
                AND ClassId = @ClassId
                AND Semester = @Semester
                AND StartTime = @StartTime
                AND EndTime = @EndTime
                AND DaySchedule = @DaySchedule)
        RAISERROR .......
        RETURN

   INSERT INTO dbo.Agenda(AgendaId, MatirelId, InstructorId, ClassId, 
                          AddedDate, Semester, StartTime, EndTime, DaySchedule)
   VALUES(@AgendaId, @MatirelId, @InstructorId, @ClassId, 
          @AddedDate, @Semester, @StartTime, @EndTime, @DaySchedule)
END
```

Read [the excellent MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592.aspx) to learn about how exactly to call `RAISERROR` to cause an error to be thrown from your stored procedure!

Comment: think it's will work , thanx for replay , i'll try it , and give u my feed  back , 
thanx  Mr.Marc_s .

Comment: In where clause i would consider NULL checks, if columns can contain null values.

Comment: @Jānis: true - the question isn't very specific and clear about that - good point, though!

Comment: Dear Marc : i'm talking about overlapping , if there an overlapping or not .!